# How to connect right click menu action to some function in QGraphicsView?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

Currently in my QGraphicsScene, there are multiple items (like Text, Ellipse, Rectangle, Polyline etc ) I want to change the color of these items by right clicking on them and then choose "Color Me" option. Once clicked on "Color Me" option, color dialog box should get pop up and then, I should change the color of item.

But in my try, on right click, Color Me option is appearing but clicking on it ColorOption slot, is not getting called.

```
   Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
        : QGraphicsView(parent)
        , ui(new Ui::Widget)
    {      
        .....
    
        myCustomAction1 = new QAction(tr("Color Me"), this);
        connect(myCustomAction1, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(ColorOption()));      
        .....
    }   



 void Widget::ColorOption()
{
    QColor color = QColorDialog::getColor(currentColor);
    if(color.isValid())
        currentColor = color;
    .....

}
```

Widget.h

```
class Widget : public QGraphicsView
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Widget();
private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
    QGraphicsScene* scene;
    QGraphicsView* view;
    QAction* myCustomAction1;
    QColor currentColor;    
};
```

I would appreciate if anyone could help.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the signal-slot mechanism to work, the slot function must be declared in the class declaration. I.e. the following needs to be in Widget.h:

```
public slots:
    void ColorOption();
```